# calculate vertex degree in sql

Tags: postgresql, graph-theory

I have a table which basically represents edges in a graph as a function of time (ideally, each date could be seen as a different graph, and that's how I am looking at it).

It's something like this, value in fromNode and toNode are of the same nature and they might be repeated (as in, a node could be in 'from' and 'to' in the same month):

```
 fromNode, toNode, date
```

Now, I want to calculate, for a given month and set of nodes, the degree (seeing the graph as undirected so no in or out-degree). I could do something like this:

```
select count(*) from mytable where (fromNode = thisvalue or toNode = thisvalue) and date = thisdate;
```

and have the degree for one node.

What is eluding me at the moment is how to extend this in such a way that it would work for a set of nodes. The expected outcome would be something like:

```
 node | degree
 -------------
 nodeA|  12
 nodeB|  0
 nodeC|  15
 ...
```

and so on. Thanks in advance.

(I am using postgresql, 9.3)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a table with all nodes (`nodeTable` with a column `node`) in it and the edge table is called `edgeTable`, then this would work:

```
select 
node, 
(select count(*) from edgeTable 
        where (fromNode=node or toNode=node) and date=thisdate) degree 
from  nodeTable
```

If you have no such thing as `nodeTable` you could build it easily with

```
select fromnode as node from edgeTable union select tonode as node from edgeTable
where date=thisdate
```

and you could use this as a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT AllNodes.node, 
       Count(*)
FROM (
   SELECT "fromNode" As node
   FROM Table1
   UNION
   SELECT "toNode"
   FROM Table1
) AllNodes
JOIN Table1  t1
ON AllNodes.node IN( t1."fromNode", t1."toNode")
-- WHERE t1.date between etc
GROUP BY AllNodes.node
ORDER BY AllNodes.node
```

Demo --> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/21faa/4